# How to add the camera as canvas background

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I have a simple app with graphics moving about on a canvas, implemented in a surfaceview, i.e. not using an xml layout.

Is there an easy way to use the camera preview as the background?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a **FrameLayout** and put first your **surfaceView** as a child and then some other view with no/transparent background.

A **FrameLayout** draws its children in the order of adding.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is it possible to do this without using an xml layout?

Comment: You could do anything programmatically